# chromeブラウザの開いているタブをjavascriptで切り替えたい

Tags: javascript

chromeの拡張機能を使用せずに(導入できない環境の為)
javascriptで複数開いているタブの遷移を行う方法はあるでしょうか。
各ページでアクティブになってからn秒経過後に次のタブに遷移するような処理を実装したいと考えています。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私が知る限り、不可能だと思います。`window.focus()`でもタブの活性化はできません。もしページのコードでこれが可能ならブラクラが簡単に作れてしまいます。

タブを複数開くのではなく、`iframe`でなんとかするのが妥当だと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
やはり厳しいですか。。
KeyboardEventでctrl+PageUp等も試してみたのですがダメでした。